# what could be the fastest way to delete all data from a partition of a partitioned table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, partitioning, delete

I have a partitioned table that in real life has 80 million rows.

for testing purposes [I have created and partitioned this table here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171343/how-to-align-data-with-an-specific-partition-plus-2-other-questions-related-to).

when I run the following query:

```
select * from countries
where visit >= '20110101'
  and visit <= '20111231'
```

as you can see [in the query plan here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryLIG_w0e) and on the picture below, it uses [partition elimination](http://littlekendra.com/2015/11/17/did-my-query-eliminate-table-partitions-sql-server/) so I know I am doing something right.

[image]

I am aware that [partition generally is not meant to speed up my queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45550/will-table-partitioning-speed-up-my-queries), it is a management feature, however, it can [speed up queries on large tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153247/how-can-i-update-statistics-adding-the-data-of-the-last-day-only).

I will start by stating what I don't want.
I don't want to [remove any partition from my table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69672/how-to-remove-a-table-partition).

what I want?

I want to delete all data from a partition in the quickest possible way:

can something be quicker than this?
[without considering deleting in batches](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/methods-of-speeding-up-a-huge-delete-from-table-with-no-clauses)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

DELETE 
FROM dbo.countries WITH (TABLOCKX)
WHERE visit >= '20110101'
  AND visit <= '20111231'

--COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
```

[query plan is here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1jqIuwRl)

[image]

Comment: I've found this method for deleting data very efficient: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Comment: yes, that is the way I normally do them big deletes, however, I wanted to see if I could take a bit more advantage on the partitioning, either for faster I/O or lock management.In  [this other comment of yours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql) is very helpful, but I am current on sql2014 not sql2016

Comment: Why don't you want to swap out the partition in question and then truncate it after the swap?  You may even be able to adjust the query in this [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/t-sql-how-to-switch-all-partitions-from-one-table-to-another) question to your needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server 2014 unfortunately doesn't support TRUNCATE on a partition. Either drop and recreate it or switch it out.

See longer discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4dc7be4b-836b-4f97-a480-4a2c5be4ac6a/drop-or-truncate-a-particular-partition?forum=transactsql).

SQL Server 2016 *does* support truncating partitions. If you're on that version, that's definitely your fastest option.

Comment: An interesting follow-up question might be: would it make sense to split a partition if you need to delete a subset of the partition, and then merge back the partition?